# ArcGIS API for JavaScript RouteParameters vs REST API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, routing, arcgis-rest-api

I have the network analysis service and I need to get the route between two points, but I don't want the single path polyline, but rather set of paths representing the edges it travels though (pretty much single path polyline broken at the network nodes).

I've found that there is a parameter called "populate_route_edges" ([link here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Route_service_with_asynchronous_execution/02r300000275000000/)) which seems to be the one parameter that will get me what I need, but I cannot find its corresponding parameter in RouteParameters object in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript.

Does anyone know, how to get the multipart polyline route result from network analysis, where the parts are the edges (segments) of the road network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the parameter you mentioned is only available via the asynchronous service documentation you've linked to, your best bet would be to make your call to it via a generic [Geoprocessor](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geoprocessor-amd.html#submitjob) Task.

this approach allows you finer grain control both in defining execution type and specifying parameters by name.

Comment: thank you. What one has to do is to publish its own geoprocessing model that will handle similar task) and send requests by using the front end Geoprocessor object. I wish the option of returning the traversed edges and junctions was out-of-the-box in Route solving

Comment: i'm not suggesting that you publish a different service, only that you use the JSAPI Geoprocessor task object to make calls to the service you already found.

Comment: yep, but we have our own routing service. I've bundled it up with some further geoprocessing tools to achieve the requirements.